# Edit XML values in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datagridview

I'm writing a programm that stores its data to XML. I got stuck on fetching data from XML to DataGridView and Editing the XML element values. I tried many codes but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? 
And which one is easier. Linq commands or XMLWriter, XMLReader ways ????
Heres the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sid = textBox1.Text;
            string fname = textBox3.Text;
            string lname = textBox2.Text;
            string address = textBox4.Text;
            string gender = radioButton1.Checked ? "эр" : "эм";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("student.xml");
            string tempid = doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Student/ID").InnerText;
            if(tempid == sid)
            {
                doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Student/Fname").InnerText = fname;
                doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Student/Lname").InnerText = lname;
                doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Student/Address").InnerText = address;
                doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Student/Gender").InnerText = gender;
            }
```

And the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<root>


-<Student>

<ID>B140030123</ID>

<FName>Kent</FName>

<LName>Wayne</LName>

<Address>Gotham</Address>

<Gender>эр</Gender>

</Student>

</root>
```

How to loop pls help :(

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sid = textBox1.Text;
            string fname = textBox3.Text;
            string lname = textBox2.Text;
            string address = textBox4.Text;
            string gender = radioButton1.Checked ? "эр" : "эм";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("student.xml");
            XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement;
            string tempid = doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Student/ID").InnerText;
            foreach (var temp in doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Student/ID"))
            {


                if (tempid == sid)
                {
                    doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Student/FName").InnerText = fname;
                    doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Student/LName").InnerText = lname;
                    doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Student/Address").InnerText = address;
                    doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Student/Gender").InnerText = gender;
                }
            }

            doc.Save("student.xml");         



        }
```

Comment: I'm assuming there is a doc.Save("student.xml") command?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the `XmlDocument` object does not change the xml file. You must overwrite the file when you are done with your edits.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("student.xml");
string tempid = doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Student/ID").InnerText;
if(tempid == sid)
{
   doc.SelectSingleNode("root/Student/Fname").InnerText = fname;
   ...etc
}  

doc.Save("student.xml");
```

Comment: ok. Now its saves the values, but if I have multiple <Student> .... </Student> then it wont save the values. Probably dont know which one to modify ????

Comment: You would have to loop over all student elements if there is more than one, but that is not relevant to the question. `Save` will save whatever changes you have made.

Comment: How to loop? I tried to foreach. (See the question edit pls)

Comment: That is a very google-able topic and should be a new question if you have trouble. I will say I prefer `XDocument` in `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Having your XML structure you can use a simple approach:

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml("student.xml");

dataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Student"];
```

That's all!

You can edit data in the `DataGridView`. You can add and delete rows.

In the end, save the `DataSet` to the file:

```
dataSet.WriteXml("student.xml");
```